# How does difficulty affect world tour in Rock Band 2?

Tags: rock-band-2

I was wondering what effect difficulty had in world tour. At first glance, it may seem that it is easier to play at easier difficulties in order to make it easier to get more stars and thus progress faster to other cities, but I suspect that there is more money and more fans to be gained by playing at higher difficulties.

If difficulty does affect world tour in some way, I have an added question. When a band is playing, is there a point of playing at expert vocals for instance as long as somebody else is playing at a lower difficulty?

Answer (score 2):

The number of total fans you can have is capped by difficulty, with no cap when playing on Expert difficulty.  Additionally, certain gigs can only be played on higher difficulties, limiting the number of stars you can acquire.  Any gig limited by some difficulty can always be played on higher difficulties, but never on lower difficulties.

The fan cap and other restrictions are determined by the player on the lowest difficulty, so in order to have no fan cap you need to have everybody playing on Expert difficulty.

Comment: the player playing at higher difficulty does generate cash and fans according to the level, although the diffrences are modest.